# Installing GitLab on 15.04 gives Upstart Error

Tags: git, 15.04

I have been trying to install Gitlab on a instance of Ubuntu 15.04.

Unfortunately when I run:

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

I get the error message:

`STDERR: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

How can I proceed...?

Comment: Can the people who left down-votes let me know why...? This was something I spent some time on and I thought it might be useful for others to know about.

Comment: Nevermind, I vote you up, I have the same problem, and it seems that developers don't want to fix it for 15.04 is not a LTS version, and I still need a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.05 no longer uses Upstart. It uses SystemD. GitLab hasn't been updated to check for this at the time of writing.

The rules that deal with this are in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/default.rb`

So one can amend the Debian rule:

```
when "debian"
  case node["platform"]
  when "debian"
    if node["platform_version"] =~ /^8/
      include_recipe "runit::systemd"
    else
      include_recipe "runit::sysvinit"
    end
  else
    include_recipe "runit::upstart"
```

to

```
when "debian"
  case node["platform"]
  when "debian"
    if node["platform_version"] =~ /^8/
      include_recipe "runit::systemd"
    else
      include_recipe "runit::sysvinit"
    end
  else
    #include_recipe "runit::upstart"
    include_recipe "runit::systemd"
```

NB: Yes, I answered my own question as I was stuck on this and wanted to share.